# What happens when Hystrix walks away cause of a timeout, and server responds with any result?

Tags: spring-rest, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

For example, I enable Hystrix on my service, client, consuming another service, server. I set the Hystrix timeout to 5 seconds. After 5 seconds, if the server doesn't responds, the Hystrix will timeout and call fallback. What happens if the server responds after Hystrix is timed-out and walked-away from that call?

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#isolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the Hystrix timeout triggers, Hystrix will send a `Thread.interrupt()` to the client side of the call. Depending on what you implemented in the Hystrix command, this might or might not have the effect on the client side of the call to abort. This [can be configured](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration) with the `execution.isolation.thread.interruptOnTimeout`.

The server part will usually continue to run. If your client side of the call wasn't aborted, it will receive the result. But the result will not be delivered to the caller of the Hystrix command. It will be discarded.

Comment: so should I send a cancel request to server (to free up the underlying resources being used) when the Hystrix timeouts ?

Comment: It is a good idea to do so. But your ability to do so might be limited by the protocol you use: if you use for example http as a protocol, there is usually no way to cancel the running request on the server side.

Comment: I have 2 scenarios, REST service calls and DB calls. I was thinking to do it on the DB calls service layer through JDBC query timeout